# navigator doesn't know accents (é, è à ....) in symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, utf-8

I read a symfony2 tutorial, but when I run my project I have a problem with é, à, è ....
I added  the tag that allow to use UTF-8 but same problem : 
here is my page index.html.twig  :

```
 <html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
</head>
 <body>
  <h1>Liste des catégories</h1>
  {% for cat in categories %}
   <p>{{ cat.nom }}</p>
  {% else %}
   <p>Aucune catégorie n'a été trouvée.</p>
  {% endfor %}
 </body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve this, thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your sourcefile is probably not actually saved as UTF-8. Check your editor settings.

Comment: I use notepad++, and I configured it like encodage=>encoder en UTF-8, but not result

Answer (score 1):

To work with UTF-8 in PHP:

1. save your files in UTF-8, without [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).
2. serve you responses with UTF-8 encoding. `<meta>` is generally not enough for this, you'll need to send the appropriate `Content-Type` http-header.
3. use a doctype, at least an html5 one: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I didn't inderstand what I must to update in my code, please explain to me more